# How to set color for MaterialBetterSpinner in normal state?

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner

I want to set color of `com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner` in normal state (i.e. without selecting). I have tried setting `colorControlActivated` and `colorControlNormal`, but no luck.

I want to change grey color of spinner as shown in following spinner:

[image]

I have set color of editText as follows:

[image]

Any type of help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

if you have to change  grey color of spinner line then use  :

**app:met_baseColor="@color/Your_color"**

**and you have to change label color , hint color , font style then use :**

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spDivision"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/DIVISION"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.1"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/DIVISION"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:met_baseColor="@color/outerspace"
                    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                    app:met_floatingLabelText="@string/DIVISION"
                 app:met_floatingLabelTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:met_floatingLabelTextSize="18dp"
                    app:met_textColor="@color/outerspace"
                    app:met_textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these attributes:

To change gray line color:

`app:met_primaryColor="@color/green"`     working for me

To change gray text colors:

```
app:met_textColor="@color/black"
app:met_textColorHint="@color/black"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:met_primaryColor` attribute e.g.:

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:met_primaryColor="#F00"/
```

Comment: This it not helping me in setting the color. It sets color only when spinner is in focused condition.